# SHAP import local_accuracy

Tags: python, metrics, shap

I'm trying to test metrics from the shap library https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/shap/benchmark/metrics.py

I tried calling metrics like this :

```
shap.benchmark.metrics.local_accuracy(X, y, model)
```

But am always getting the error :

```
AttributeError: module 'shap' has no attribute 'benchmark'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead:

```
from shap.benchmark import metrics
metrics.local_accuracy(X, y, model)
```

Why? Inspecting package's top level `__init__.py` you'll find out the following commented line:

```
#from . import benchmark
```